# The word scramble

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does " they scrambled it" mean in the dialogue seen in the picture.

Is it when dots or pixels are gotten bigger so people cannot see details in a picture or movie scene?

[image]

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrambler. I think back in the analog days, it would look quite like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjTLF1wn2xs.

Comment: @Damkerng T. Thanks .I think the joke was made here by referring premium channels..Do you use the word scramble when premium( not free) channels deliberately distort the vision? And I would like to ask which word is used when only small part of a scene was blurred?  For example cigarette..

Comment: Yes (imho) to the first, and blurring to the second. I don't think that kind of blurring is scrambling. It's more about censorship, which is different from scrambling. The techniques employed in scrambling and censorship could be overlapping, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scramble can mean:

- to jumble an image up so it is not understandable
- to mix a set of items and/or parts of a single item, destroying any existing order
- to run in a chaotic manner (not maintaining current order)
- a method of cooking eggs where the yolk and white are mixed together.

What you describe:

> Is it when dots or pixels are gotten bigger so people cannot see details in a picture or movie scene?

is not scrambling per se.  As you can see above, scrambling is about rearranging randomly, but not removing items.  The term "pixellation" or "mosaic effect" can be used to describe that.  If you mean a small area used to censor something, "pixellated out" would express that.